# About grails In my office tell me about CRUD must be code in service why?

Tags: grails, service, crud

Today I have present about CRUD in grails When I show source code friend tell me it incorrect cause it's not code in service almost coding by use gen controller(this active record correct??)

why me code CRUD in service ?? I dont understand plz suggest me

Comment: I really hope that you are using an automated translation for this, because that was extremely difficult to understand. If you are trying to ask: Why is it suggested to put CRUD code inside of a service rather than in the controller itself? Maybe people can give you an advise, but centrality not a definite answer

Comment: Thank you so much for answer & suggest ,Sir. I will trying to new question (I not use auto translate:( but my eng is not good for communicate )

Answer (score 0):

Doing read only operations in a controller is ok.  The reason write operations should be done in a service is because services are transactional by default.  If you write to more than 1 table at a time in a controller, and one of them fails, you will have corrupt / incomplete data.

If you do the same in a transactional service, all changes rollback, which is what you want.  While there might "centrality not a definite answer", this is common pattern/practice that goes even beyond Grails.